# Display products based on sidemenu Onsen-UI

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

I populated the sidemenu from opencart categories and the main page from the products but I'm stuck at displaying certain products that comes under a particular category.

i.e when I click 'PC' side menu, the right page should load the products under 'PC' dynamically.

In this snippet, I populated the menu pointing to a static page 'page1.html'

```
<ons-list class="menu-list">
<!-- Enter menu items here -->
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="category in category" class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
{{category.Category_Name}}
</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

In this snippet, i populated all the products in that page 'page1.html'

```
<li ng-repeat="product in getCurrentPage()">
<ul class="cd-item-wrapper">
<li class="cd-item-front"><a ng-click="showDetails(product);"><img ng-src="http://localhost/oc/image/{{product.Imageo}}" height=250px width=100% alt="Preview image"></a>
</li>
```

Both JSON (one for products and other for categories) data has category_id linking the categories and their respective products.

here is my codepen to my full learning project http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/LERLpe

any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

UPDATE 3: I tried to do this with my program but i don't know where to start, still working on this. http://plnkr.co/edit/MgltNXw0x2KWcmWm6QeA?p=preview

Comment: What have you tried so far? When the user clicks on a category I guess it should load the products but it just changes the main page. You should load the data there and populate your scope.

Comment: so I need to pass the category id through a function which pushes the page that populates the products based on the category id (like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577793/push-a-page-dynamically-using-onsenui?noredirect=1#comment43620862_27577793). I'm gonna try it now. Thanks man.

Comment: And i can use angularjs filter to show the product, right?. Correct me if i am wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to filter products based on category id,

In HTML

```
...
<li ng-repeat="product in products|categorySelector:categoryID">
...
```

In JS

```
    ...
    module.filter('categorySelector', function(){

        return function(products, id){

            var returnProduct = [];        
            for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++){
                if (products[i].Category_Id == id) {
                    returnProduct.push(products[i]);
                }
            }

            return returnProduct;
        };
    });
...
$scope.showProducts = function(Category_ID) {
          $scope.categoryID = Category_ID;
          $scope.slidingMenu.setMainPage('page1.html',{closeMenu:true});
        };
    ...
```

see my new forked codepen http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/xbEPyj